# Rails: Reset a model attribute at specific time each day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, reset

I have a rails app with a `Location` model, which has a `rating`, and a `rating_count` field. Now, I need to reset every `Location`'s `rating` and `rating_count`attributes to 0 at a specific time everyday, lets say 12:00:00 UTC.

How would I accomplish this? I'm using the default `sqlite3` databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to use cron. You can find tons of documentation out there!Although if you are running a Rails app you should check out [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever/) a pretty neat gem for managing cron jobs for your app!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to write a rake task that does that job, and then use whatever scheduling system your host uses (cron).

An alternative is to use [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) which allows to push work to a background process. While delayed-job is not exactly suited for something like this, it is perfectably capable of doing this. If your rails process starts, you add a new job, to run at 12:00. And the running of the job reschedules the job.

The nice thing of delayed-job is that your code runs in the context of a rails-process, so you can use methods you already have. Also nice: jobs are stored in the database, so you can have an overview.

Comment: Alright, I'll go with a rake task and cron I guess. So the 'rake task' is simply a migration that uses `remove_column` on `rating` and `rating_count`, and then `add_column` `rating` and `rating_count` correct?

Comment: Just set the values to zero. The easiest way to do this is use `Location.update_all("rating = 0, rating_count =0")`. Documentation for `update_all` is http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a *nix box, write a script to do the updates (eg. in PHP, or Perl) and simply add it to crontab. Check out [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).