# Automatically create instance of a model every day with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduled-tasks

I am writing an app with 2 models, User and Daily. Each user has_many dailies. I am trying to create a Daily report for each user every day at midnight. How do I do this in rails? In Backbone, I would just find the time between now and midnight, set a timeout for that amount of time, and then create a new model, and call that function recursively. I looked at [Rails: Reset a model attribute at specific time each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105797/rails-reset-a-model-attribute-at-specific-time-each-day) and saw the suggestion to use whenever and cron, but I wasn't sure if there was a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

A temporary solution I came up with was to create a new Daily when a user visits the home page if the current user doesn't already have a Daily with today's date. This has the problem of only creating the report for a day if the user visits the homepage on that day. If the user navigates around the homepage, the report won't be created, and I think it's too intrusive a solution to put that check in every action. Is there a way in rails to automate this task?

Edit: Another idea I had was to put an after_create into my Daily class, and then use the same solution as my Backbone solution. Is that the optimal way to accomplish this?

Comment: you should add a cron task which will run in midnight everyday. YOu should create a task inside your lib/tasks. Run the cron task. You can consult your server system engineer to add cron task to your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the gem [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

It allows you to define tasks in a very readable DSL in a `config/schedule.rb` file like this: (examples taken from gem readme):

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end

every :hour do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot
  runner "SomeModel.ladeeda"
end

every :sunday, :at => '12pm' do # Use any day of the week or :weekend, :weekday
  runner "Task.do_something_great"
end

every '0 0 27-31 * *' do
  command "echo 'you can use raw cron syntax too'"
end

# run this task only on servers with the :app role in Capistrano
# see Capistrano roles section below
every :day, :at => '12:20am', :roles => [:app] do
  rake "app_server:task"
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the gem I was looking at and after some work everything is working great.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a background or asynchronous function, so you would better not place the logic in views or the client side. It's not reliable. The easiest way is cron however it's OS dependent. Cron also has other disadvantages. If you want a pure ruby solution, I suggest gem  clockwork. See details: https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork